# iOS 7-8 Background Timer

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, background-process

I've searched a lot and didn't find anything that helps. Basically I need to develop an app, that vibrates every X minutes in time interval (provided by user, from 15 to 180 min), also it must be executed in background. Can this be achieved?

UPD:
It should play sound, vibrate or both of these. For example: user selects 40 mins, and sound should be played every 3 minutes. It must play/vibrate in background and foreground, after time passes, notifications should simply stop.

Comment: Can it show the user an alert? Does it have to stop automatically?

Comment: You probably can't do that in background without doing nasty stuff. Timer will stop when the app will go to sleep

Comment: The appropriate technique would be local notification, with all of the constraints and limitations that entails. See [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html)